# Visual Studio debugger - source search directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a crash dump (minidump, mdmp format) for an executable (native x86 code) compiled on a different computer. I have the pdb + exe corresponding to the crash dump, they are located next to the crashdump, and debugger recognizes them correctly. The pdb references sources on a path which is not available on my computers (say `E:\Project`). When I first opened the crash dump, the debugger has asked me for the source location. I pointed it to `E:\B\Project` on my computer, however once the source window appeared, I realized my choice was wrong (the sources were for a different product branch). I would like to point the debugger to a correct location `E:\D\Project`, however the debugger is no longer asking me. There is no solution, project or opt file for the crashdump created. I have searched the registry, but I did not find `E:\B\Project` anywhere.

How can one set/change source directories for Visual Studio debugger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found one way, not very intuitive, but it works:

- create a new Visual C++ project and solution (it may be created anywhere, but a location next to the mdmp file seems convenient)
- or use a Visual C++ project and solution you normally use to build the executable
- set up source location in `Solution` (Right click) > `Common Properties` > `Debug Source Files` > `Directories containing source code`
- open the crash dump using `File` > `Open` > `File` > select `Dump Files` as a filter

*Note: crash dump analysis guides on the internet can be misleading when they are not recent enough, as dump files are no longer opened as projects since 2010, they are opened as files instead. See [a note by R Nitzel in the MSDN Crash Dump Analysis article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).*

Comment: +1 for complete steps. On one MS forum, i read a suggestion to put  binary files/assemblies, .pdb/symbol files and source files together... nevertheless i prefer your method.

Comment: Somehow this does not work for me with existing solution and MSVS Community 2013 Update 5 :(

Comment: @mlt Can you be more specific? Which step fails, or which step are you unable to perform? Is there some error, or what "does not work"?

Comment: @Suma I tend to think it was a false alarm on my part. I had `/GL` flag that invalidated `/Zi`. I still need to check few things to confirm. It still did not show source code but disassembly only once I followed all steps. Also I tried to create an NTFS junction point to match source location on build machine. And that made me pondering about `/GL`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to specify the directories containing the source code with:
`Solution` (Right click) > `Common Properties` > `Debug Source Files` > `Directories containing source code`

Comment: I open the mdmp file and the IDE opens. There is no solution, and I see no option to create one.